# ConfusionMatrix Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels

Tags: r

Hello guys i face the error like this, i'm a newbie i dont know what that's mean. i use the neuralnet function to classification the titanic dataset

Any suggest??

> str(Prediksi)

```
 num [1:143] 0.393 0.393 0.393 0.393 0.393 ...
```

> str(test)

```
num [1:143, 1:10] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:143] "1" "3" "9" "15" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:10] "(Intercept)" "Survived" "Pclass" "Sexmale" ...
```

> confusionMatrix(Prediksi,test)

```
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
```

Comment: Your test set probably had a different set of marginals than had your train set.

Answer (score 2):

In `confusionMatrix` function, both terms needed to be a factor with same levels. Both your `Prediksi` and `test` are not a factor.

For example,

```
confusionMatrix(iris$Species, iris$Species)
```

this will works that `str(iris$Species)` returns

```
Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

However, `caret::confusionMatrix` will not allow `character`.

Take a look at `confusionMatrix(iris$Species, as.character(iris$Species))`,

this will return

```
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
```

Also, with `numeric` variable will not works.

```
confusionMatrix(iris$Species, iris$Sepal.Length)

Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
```

You provide not enough information about your task, so it's hard to say about how to solve your case, but try make both terms in `confusionMatrix` function as a factor with same levels.